# Export MySQL table as JSON using Toad

Tags: mysql, json, csv, toad

I have a MySQL table and I have to convert it either to JSON or CSV using Toad.

Converting to CSV has some issues as one of the columns in the table has commas in it. Thus JSON is the only option left.

Is there a way I can convert the table to JSON directly using Toad?

Comment: JSON isn't listed in the wiki for Toad MySQL, but XML is. Can you use that? If not, perhaps export to XML and use one of the many free tools to convert XML to JSON.

Comment: I think this would work . thanks